# WebSocketServer on ESP32 DevkitC V4 Issue

Tags: websocket, esp32

I'm developing a simple mobile robot controlled by a custom web application hosted on ESP32. The communication protocol that is used is WebSocket. I had a code that was working but after some break, I can't make it run properly again... most likely I changed something accidentally or I don't understand some code parts. The logs in SerialPort suggest that the program connects to the WiFi, it gets data (HTML files) from Flash memory and the server is started under some particular IP. However, when I try to access the server IP nothing is given in response. I pasted my .ino code down below, I can also add HTML and .js files if needed. The data folder is ofc uploaded to the flash memory. For now I just want to host that page on a server and access it, the code is not supposed to do anything else for now. I'm going crazy because of that issue. Does anyone see some mistake or misconception?

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include "SPIFFS.h"
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>

// Network credentials
const char *ssid = "mySSID";
const char *password = "myCredentials";

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);

// Create a WebSocket object
AsyncWebSocket ws("/ws");

// Placeholder for messages from the clients
String message = "";

void initFS()
{
  if (!SPIFFS.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("An error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("SPIFFS mounted successfully");
  }
}

// Initialise WiFi
void initWiFi()
{
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void handleWebSocketMessage(void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
  AwsFrameInfo *info = (AwsFrameInfo *)arg;
  if (info->final && info->index == 0 && info->len == len && info->opcode == WS_TEXT)
  {
    data[len] = 0;
    message = (char *)data;
  }
}

void onEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, AsyncWebSocketClient *client, AwsEventType type, void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
  switch (type)
  {
  case WS_EVT_CONNECT:
    Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u connected from %s\n", client->id(), client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
    break;
  case WS_EVT_DISCONNECT:
    Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u disconnected\n", client->id());
    break;
  case WS_EVT_DATA:
    handleWebSocketMessage(arg, data, len);
    break;
  case WS_EVT_PONG:
  case WS_EVT_ERROR:
    break;
  }
}

void initWebSocket()
{
  Serial.println("I'm Inside!");
  ws.onEvent(onEvent);
  server.addHandler(&ws);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Initialising SPIFFS");
  initFS();

  Serial.println("Initialising WiFi");
  initWiFi();

  Serial.println("Initialising WebSocket");
  initWebSocket();

  // Web Server Root URL
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
            { request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", "text/html"); });

  server.serveStatic("/", SPIFFS, "/");

  // Start server
  server.begin();
  
  Serial.println("Starting Server");
}

void loop()
{
  ws.cleanupClients();
}
```

Update:
I created a different, very simple sketch just to have a look if it might work and it doesn't. It connects to the WiFi according to the logs but I'm getting timed out when I try to access the server IP address Down below is the code that I used for the second sketch:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

//SSID and Password to the local WiFi
const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";

WebServer server(80);

String webpage = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head> <meta charset='UTF-8'> <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'> <title>Document</title></head><body> <h1> Test! </h1></body></html>";

//Function to initialise the connection with local WiFi
void InitWiFi()
{  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Trying to connect to the WiFi with SSID: " + String(ssid) + "..");

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
}
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi with the IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  InitWiFi();

  //Initialising WebServer
  server.on("/", []() {
  server.send(200, "text\html", webpage);
  });

  delay(1000);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
 
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Hi @MRTX29 - can you be more clear about exactly what you're doing and what you expect to happen? Is the problem with web sockets or with serving HTML? If it's with HTML exactly what URL are you trying to access, and from what? If it's with web sockets, what are you sending and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @romkey Hi, thanks for your comment. I’m expecting from this program to setup the web server. I uploaded to ESP32 the data folder which contains index.html along with .css and .js files that it uses. The program prints some localhost ip in the serial monitor. I’d like to see that index.html file after typing that IP in browser (it worked like previously, I just messed something up).